# Preventing jQuery timepicker addon from automatically opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

Does anyone know of a method to prevent the [jQuery timepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) from automatically opening up when the textbox is focused? The documentation doesn't seem to provide a way and I'm currently looking at the source seeing if I can add the functionality ***but have I overlooked a simple way to accomplish this?***

Comment: When do you want the time picker to open?

Comment: At some point later. For example a button press.

Comment: Then don't call `$('#yourelement').datetimepicker();` until the button click event is fired.

Comment: Not a bad idea but then the user still needs 2 focus onto the textbox again... Also: the problem is that I might (for example) never want the focus event of the textbox to trigger the popup...

Comment: Find another event where you want the `datetimepicker` removed from your textbox. Maybe the close event of `datetimepicker` ? Maybe another button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just initiate the `datetimepicker` upon the button clicked (as well as focus the input box), and destroy the object when the picker is closed?

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
           $(this).datetimepicker('destroy');
        }
    }).focus();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/NRH9r/

Comment: Clever and much better then what I came up with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to use a jquery function called unbind() to remove the onfocus event from the datetimepicker. You can then call an instance of the datetime picker when you fire a click event, or any other event you wish to fire. Another option would be to call the onfocus event that fires the datetimepicker, And pass in an event object into the callback function. Then call for example event.preventDefault(). This will prevent the onfocus() event from doing what it normally does.

Comment: your simplest solution would be  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selector').datepicker({ showOn: 'button' });
        });

Answer (score 0):

As the timepicker is an addon to the jquery ui datepicker, you can use the [showOn](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOn) option  to specify that a button is used to trigger it. See the datepicker example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger).

Here's an example of how this can be used for the time picker:

```
 $('input:text.timepicker').timepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/content/images/time_icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
```